# when is the SQL ROLLBACK command used?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, graphql

I'm trying to write a test file for my signInUser mutation for an app. I'm using Ruby on Rails with GraphQL API. My test file is returning an error because the user is returning null for some reason. This is my mutation file:

```
module Mutations
  class SignInUser < BaseMutation
    argument :auth, Types::AuthProviderEmailInput, required: false

    field :token, String, null: true
    field :user, Types::UserType, null: true

    def resolve(auth: nil)
      # basic validation
      return unless auth

      user = User.where('uuid=? OR email=?', auth[:user_id], auth[:user_id]).first()

      # ensures we have the correct user
      return unless user && user.is_active
      return unless user.authenticate(auth[:password])

      user.update_attributes(invitation_status: true) if !user.invitation_status

      { user: user, token: AuthToken.token(user) }
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my test file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Mutations::SignInUserTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def perform(args = {})
        Mutations::SignInUser.new(object: nil, field: nil, context: {}).resolve(args)
    end

    test 'sign in user' do
        post "server-url.com"

        user = perform(
            auth: {
                user_id: "example",
                password: "example"
            }
        )

        assert user.persisted?
    end
end
```

When I run the test file this is what it returns:

```
Error:
Mutations::SignInUserTest#test_sign_in_user:
NoMethodError: undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass
    test/graphql/mutations/sign_in_user_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:SignInUserTest>
```

so the user is null and not signed in. I checked the test.log file in my log folder and this is what happened when I ran the test file:

```
Started POST "/graphql" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-06-15 22:12:33 +0700
Processing by GraphqlController#execute as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND (uuid='example' OR email='example') ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK[0m
```

I can confirm that the user is in the database, since signing in on the app or on Altair works, but this doesn't. I searched that ROLLBACK is an SQL command that reverts the changes not yet saved. Is this command ran when the SELECT query returns null? The SELECT query should return the user but I don't know why it won't. Is the problem not on my end but on the server end?

Comment: what else is going on in GraphqlController#execute? Are you updating / creating any records? Rollback is usually fired by ActiveRecord after a failed transaction. So for example if you are updating a record and one of it's callbacks fail - Rails will rollback the transaction

Comment: @Joel I managed to pinpoint the problem, it rollbacked because for some reason my SQL tables are empty when I checked them with exec_query in the test file. It's weird because when I check MySQL the tables have data, and the staging site that my POST request is sent to definitely has data. I guess now I have to figure out how to populate the tables.

Comment: Ah you are running the code in a test?

Comment: @Joel yea this is for a test suite that I'm writing for our GraphQL API

Comment: All tests in Rails run inside a transaction. You will always have a rollback in the end of the test, that is what allows Rails to keep the test database clean between tests.